# What is SignImm in Branch Target Address formula context? (BTA)

Tags: assembly, mips, memory-address, immediate-operand, instruction-encoding

I would like to know what is SignImm in the following formula:

```
BTA = Branch Target Address = PC(old) + 4 + (SignImm << 2)
```

I have read that it is the address distance between the old PC + 4 and the new target address, but I have not seen it in a clear example. Could anyone explain me in an example please? I appreciate all the help, I am trying to learn assembly :)

```
0x00400000 addi $s0, $0, 4 # $s0 = 0 + 4 = 4
0x00400004 addi $s1, $0, 1 # $s1 = 0 + 1 = 1
0x00400008 sll $s1, $s1, 2 # $s1 = 1 << 2 = 4
0x0040000C bne $s0, $s1, target 
0x00400010 addi $s1, $s1, 1 # $s1 = 4 + 1 = 5
0x00400014 sub $s1, $s1, $s0 # $s1 = 5 – 4 = 1
. . . . . .
0x004000FC target:
add $s1, $s1, $s0
```

```
BTA = PC + 4 + (SignImm << 2)
SignImm = (BTA-PC-4) >> 2
SignImm = (0x004000FC-0x0040000C-4) >> 2
SignImm = (0x000000F0-4) >> 2
SignImm = (0x000000EC) >> 2
SignImm = 0x0000003B = 59
```

So with this example 59 should be the distance between old PC + 4 and the target, but I have added 59 to 0x00400010 and it is not 0x004000FC...

Comment: `SignImm` is the **Sign**ed **Imm**ediate encoded into the instruction word.

Comment: @fuz I know that is the 16 bit imm that is located in the i type instruction word, but I would like to know, what is that used for

Comment: The immediate is what gives the location of the branch target as an offset from the current address in words.

Comment: I understand, but I have tried to calculate the difference distance in an example and it doesn't correspond to the SignImm, this is why I would like it to see it in an example please, thanks

Comment: If you post the example you tried to work out, I can try and help you find out what the problem is.

Comment: @fuz I have edited the post with an example, check it

Comment: I don't understand your calculations.  The distance is `BTA-PC`.  59 is what you get when you subtract 4 from that and shift right by 2 (which is what is encoded in the instruction word).

Comment: So what is 59 representing then? I don't understand what is representing that 59...

Comment: 59 is what is stored as an immediate in the instruction word.

Answer (score 1):

All of your instructions reside at an address that is divisible by 4.
If the branch distance were to be encoded as a true **byte**-distance then that number would have its 2 low bits zero all the time. This is wasteful. The encoding therefore uses the **dword**-distance, thereby enabling branches that reach 4x farther.

```
0x0040000C + 4 bytes + 0x3B dwords  

0x0040000C + 4 bytes + 0xEC bytes  

0x0040000C + 0x000000F0 bytes

0x004000FC
```